# IF Condition in master-detail ORACLE DATABASE

Tags: sql, oracle

Im a newbie in database programming. I have a question regarding master-detail structure and using IF statement for the operation.

So i have master table,

```
MASTER,
ID   
NOTE1
NOTE2

DETAIL,
ID     ITEM   STATUS
NOTE1  BOOKA   DELIVERED
NOTE1  BOOKB   NOTDELIVERED
NOTE2  BOOKA   DELIVERED
NOTE2  BOOKC   DELIVERED
```

So i have this kind of logic in the query that if the status of all items in detail are DELIVERED  then it has to print DELIVERED when user query the note1 from the MASTER. Otherwise it has to print NOTDELIVERED if all the items are not delivered.

```
SELECT M.ID, (IF-Condition to check all the items in details D) FROM MASTER M JOIN DETAIL.D ON M.ID = D.ID
```

Please help me on how to approach this

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on quantities of data (number of master records, number of detail records), distributions of DELIVERED and NOTDELIVERED one might do this differently, but I would probably do:

```
SELECT m.ID
, CASE WHEN NVL(NOTDELIVERED_COUNT,0) = 0 THEN 'DELIVERED' ELSE 'NOTDELIVERED' END AS DELIVERED
FROM MASTER m
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID
    , COUNT(*) NOTDELIVERED_COUNT
    FROM DETAIL
    WHERE STATUS = 'NOTDELIVERED'
    GROUP BY ID
) d ON d.ID = m.ID
```

So having a sub-query pull together the IDs with undelivered items and checking whether that is there joined to the master (`LEFT JOIN` so that the IDs without NOTDELIVERED items come through as `NULL`)

Comment: Isn't that the other way around ? Printing NOTDELIVERED if not delivered count >0 ?

Comment: It was the wrong way round - thanks @X.L.Ant! - fixed now :-)

Comment: @Captain I have one more question, what if i want to add third case PARTIALLYDELIVERED when NOTDELIVERED_COUNT > 0 and DELIVERED_COUNT >= 1 ???

Comment: Hi, this will make knowing your data and querying a bit important - in my first query, I worked from the assumption that there will be a small fraction of a big set of data NOTDELIVERED... If we include a DELIVERED_COUNT in the same manner, we could have worse performance than if we did a correlated subquery... How will you really query this data? How much data are ewe talking about?

Answer (score -1):

here is the solution as per your given data and i didn't used master table because if its a header and detail relation then foreign key constraint must be there.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DT.ID,
CASE WHEN TOT=1 AND STATUS='DELIVERED' THEN 'DELIVERED' ELSE 'UNDELIVERED' END STAT
FROM
   (
    SELECT ID,COUNT(1) TOT
    FROM (
           select de.id,wm_concat(de.ITEM),status from  detail de
            group by id,status
         ) GROUP BY ID
   ) DH,DETAIL DT,MASTERD MA
WHERE DT.ID=DH.ID
 AND DT.ID=MA.ID;
```

OR you can use this one

```
select distinct ma.id,
    (
    case when count(1) in (select count(d.id) from detail d where d.id=de.id ) 
    and de.status='DELIVERED' then 'DELIVERED' 
    else 'UNDELIVERED'   end
    ) status 
from masterd ma,detail de
where ma.id=de.id
group by ma.id,de.status,de.id 
order by 1;
```

Now this will work fine .

Comment: Your first query will omit master rows without any associated detail rows. And your second query prints the wrong result for a master record with exactly one detail record and status 'DELIVERED'.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, no its not so ,as of given data my query is returning correct result in both the cases as i did it practically then only i posted it ... also i mentioned about the referential integrity for case that why i didn't used master.

Comment: Your query *happens* to work for the example data provided, but nevertheless is the `WHEN COUNT(1) > 1` in your second query just plain wrong. Try adding a third master with one detail and status `DELIVERED` and check what happens.

Comment: Yes you were correct @FrankSchmitt so now i edited the query and made it correct please check ... Thanks for correcting me about it and even i joined first one with master.